Why does csv consider data in one column to be an empty string
I have a powershell script, which basically takes an xlsx file with data, converts it to csv and then fills certain cells in another (template) xlsx file with values from certain columns. There are many conditions about the functionalities and how to fill in the cells but I suppose it's not necessary to explain the script in detail. I face a problem:
There's one column in the csv that's causing trouble. When the column is named "protokol", everything works as intended. But when it's named "pořadové číslo protokolu", all its values are suddenly treated as an empty string. And no, non-ASCII characters are not the problem as other columns with those characters work normally. Also multiple words are not the problem because another column with two words works normally. And I don't think that there should be a difference between two-word name and three-word name.
Seemingly it's an insignificant problem, just name the column in the source file "protokol" and issue goes away, right? Wrong. The script is used in a bureau where people are used to have the file in a certain format, certain values etc. and the processes are set and not that easy to change. It's way easier to somehow fix the script :-)
Here's the whole script as it works with the "protokol" name of the column:
# Import Excel module
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Add necessary assemblies for file and folder dialogs
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function Show-MessageBox {
    param (
        [string]$message
    )
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, "Information", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
}

function Select-FolderDialog {
    $folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $folderBrowser.Description = "Select the target folder"
    $folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $true

    if ($folderBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder selection canceled."
        exit
    }
}

function Select-FileDialog {
    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileBrowser.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx"
    $fileBrowser.Title = "Select a file"

    if ($fileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $fileBrowser.FileName
    } else {
        Write-Host "File selection canceled."
        exit
    }
}

# Display messages and prompt for input using dialogs
Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber cílovou složku."
$targetFolder = Select-FolderDialog

Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber zdrojový soubor"
$dataFilePath = Select-FileDialog

Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber šablonu"
$templateFilePath = Select-FileDialog

# Create or clear the errors.log file
$logFilePath = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath "errors.log"
Clear-Content -Path $logFilePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item -Path $logFilePath -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null

# Convert data file from XLSX to CSV with UTF-8 encoding
$dataCsvPath = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath "data.csv"
$excelData = Import-Excel -Path $dataFilePath
$excelData | Export-Csv -Path $dataCsvPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

# Load CSV data
$data = Import-Csv -Path $dataCsvPath -Encoding UTF8

# Identify duplicates in the protocol column
$groupedData = $data | Group-Object -Property protokol
$duplicates = $groupedData | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }

# Create new CSV files for each group of duplicates
foreach ($group in $duplicates) {
    $protocolValue = $group.Name
    $protocolSafe = $protocolValue -replace '/', '-'
    $protocolCsvPath = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath "$protocolSafe.csv"
    $group.Group | Export-Csv -Path $protocolCsvPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

    # Remove rows from the main data file
    $data = $data | Where-Object { $_.protokol -ne $protocolValue }
}

# Export the updated main data file without duplicates
$data | Export-Csv -Path $dataCsvPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

# Process the main data file
foreach ($row in $data) {
    try {
        # Open the template file
        $workbook = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $templateFilePath

        # Get the first worksheet
        $worksheet = $workbook.Workbook.Worksheets[1]

        # Convert price to string and ensure proper format
        $priceStr = [string]$row.cena
        if ($priceStr -notmatch ',') {
            $priceStr += ",00"
        } elseif ($priceStr -match ',\d$') {
            $priceStr += "0"
        }

        # Fill in the template with data from the CSV row
        $worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "DSP5 - " + $row.protokol
        $worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = $row.předmět
        $worksheet.Cells["A5"].Value = $row.druh + "/" + $row.'inv. číslo' + "/" + $row.rok.Substring(2)
        $worksheet.Cells["B5"].Value = "koupeno 20" + $row.rok.Substring(2)
        $worksheet.Cells["C5"].Value = $priceStr + "/" + $priceStr
        $worksheet.Cells["A8"].Value = $row.důvod
        $worksheet.Cells["A10"].Value = $row.likvidace
        $worksheet.Cells["A34"].Value = $row.likvidace

        # Generate the new file name
        $protocolSafe = $row.protokol -replace '/', '-'
        $subjectSafe = $row.předmět -replace '/', '-' -replace ':', ''
        $newFileName = "$protocolSafe - $subjectSafe"
        $newFileName = $newFileName -replace '"', 'inch '
        $newFilePath = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath "$newFileName.xlsx"
        $newFilePath = $newFilePath -replace '"', 'inch '

        # Save the modified template file
        $workbook.SaveAs($newFilePath)
        Write-Host "Soubor uložen: $newFilePath"

        # Close the workbook
        $workbook.Dispose()
    } catch {
         Zaznamenání chyb do error.log
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $row.protokol
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $_.Exception.Message
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value ""
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value ""
    }
}

# Ensure the current directory is set to the target folder before processing protocol files
Set-Location -Path $targetFolder

# Process each protocol file
$protocolFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $targetFolder -Filter "*.csv" | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "data.csv" }
foreach ($protocolFilePath in $protocolFiles) {
    try {
        $protocolData = Import-Csv -Path $protocolFilePath -Encoding UTF8
        $protocol = $protocolData[0].protokol
        $protocolSafe = $protocol -replace '/', '-'
        $shortestSubject = ($protocolData | Sort-Object { $_.předmět.Length })[0].předmět
        $subjectSafe = $shortestSubject -replace '/', '-' -replace ':', '-'
        $numRows = $protocolData.Count

        # Create a parameter for inventory number
        $kindsInventoryYears = $protocolData | ForEach-Object { $_.druh + "/" + $_.'inv. číslo' + "/" + $_.rok.Substring($_.rok.Length - 2) }
        $invNumber = ($kindsInventoryYears -join ", ")

        # Create a parameter for overall price
        $totalPrice = ($protocolData | Measure-Object -Property cena -Sum).Sum

        # Create a parameter for price per piece
        $avgPricePerKs = ($totalPrice / $numRows).ToString()
        if ($avgPricePerKs -notmatch ',') {
            $avgPricePerKs += ",00"
        } elseif ($avgPricePerKs -match ',\d$') {
            $avgPricePerKs += "0"
        }
        $avgPrice = "$avgPricePerKs/ks"

        # Open the template file
        $workbook = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $templateFilePath

        # Get the first worksheet
        $worksheet = $workbook.Workbook.Worksheets[1]

        # Fill in the template with data from the CSV row
        $worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "DSP5 - " + $protocol
        $worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "$shortestSubject $($numRows)ks"
        $worksheet.Cells["A5"].Value = $invNumber
        $worksheet.Cells["B5"].Value = "koupeno 20" + $protocolData[0].rok.Substring($protocolData[0].rok.Length - 2)
        $worksheet.Cells["C5"].Value = "$totalPrice/$totalPrice ($avgPrice)"
        $worksheet.Cells["A8"].Value = $protocolData[0].důvod
        $worksheet.Cells["A10"].Value = $protocolData[0].likvidace
        $worksheet.Cells["A34"].Value = $protocolData[0].likvidace

        # Generate the new file name
        $newFileName = "$protocolSafe - $subjectSafe ($numRows ks)"
        $newFileName = $newFileName -replace '"', 'inch '
        $newFilePath = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath "$newFileName.xlsx"
        $newFilePath = $newFilePath -replace '"', 'inch '

        # Save the modified template file
        $workbook.SaveAs($newFilePath)
        Write-Host "File saved: $newFilePath"

        # Close the workbook
        $workbook.Dispose()
    } catch {
        # Log the error to errors.log
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $protocolData[0].protokol
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $_.Exception.Message
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value ""
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value ""
    }
}

# Delete all CSV files in the target folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $targetFolder -Filter "*.csv" | Remove-Item -Force

Write-Host "Script execution completed."

I tried to rewrite all the "protokol" variables everywhere to "pořadové číslo protokolu" (in apostrophes of course as it is multiple words) but it didn't work. I also tried this solution to modify the csv before its import but it also didn't work:
$excelData | Select-Object @{Name='protokol';Expression={$_.PSObject.Properties['pořadové číslo protokolu'].Value}}, subject, kind, 'inventory number', year, price, reason, liquidation | Export-Csv -Path $dataCsvPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Whenever I use the long name, the values are treated as an empty string. How do I solve the issue and let the script use the original column name from the source file? The most relevant part is in the "process the main data file" section and "process each protocol file" secion

...probably because there is an error. The general problem with your script approach is that your Try block is too large. Therefore you probably missed one or more non-terminating errors before you catch the terminating error. My advise: make small Try/Catch blocks or better: insert conditions that could lead to an error. Specific to you issue: as "pořadové číslo protokolu" contains spaces, you will need to quote it. A quick solution might be to put $protokol = 'pořadové číslo protokolu' at the beginning and replace the rest of the protokol entries with $protokol.

There's a lot of code in your sample and I'm struggling to see where the part you're describing as the problem even exists - can you try to distill it down to just the code necessary to reproduce the issue? (Going through that process is useful for debugging in itself as sometimes the problem becomes obvious all on its own :-)). Adding some sample data that works and some that fails would also be helpful to visualise the problem...

Why do you export $excelData and import it again from csv ? what is bad to use $excelData directly?
Also, how looks the data in $data? run $data | Format-Table and shows us the results.

I now discovered another problem. I found out, that my previous statement about two words long name of column functioning normally was not true. The other two-word column is also treated as empty. When I looked at the generated csv (opened it in excel), I found out, that often times the cells in the first row are on two rows - the export-csv basically presses "Alt+Enter" between the words instead of a spacebar. I tried to delete the first row in the source excel and recreate it but the problem persists.

I also tried to rename "inv. číslo" to "inv_číslo" but when I look in the csv, I still see "inv. číslo" with Alt+Enter instead of a spacebar. I have no idea what's happening.

I would recommend you against using a break space ("Alt+Enter", [char]160) for a key or name as it "conveniently" might look look a space but it simply is not: @{ "Two$([char]160)words" = 3 }.ContainsKey( 'Two words' ) --> $false

I now found out that PowerShell, for some reason, was not rewriting variables when script was run and kept using the same values over and over without changing the column names. So even if I fixed the excel file, the old values persisted. So I closed the PS session, reopened it, but now the Import-Excel function runs forever. But I guess that's for another question.

So basically the problem was, that the script was searching for words separated by a space but in the header they were separated by a new line. That's why the script couldn't find the values, and because powershell didn't rewrite variables when the script was run again, no changes in the file helped as they were ignored. So far I never encountered this problem with variables not being rewritten during new script launch. Probably an error in the Import-Excel function
